# how to store title of two urls in an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

```
import bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.core.base import DataError
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import requests
import pandas as pd
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


urls = ['https://www.digikala.com/search/category-mobile',  'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-tablet-ebook-reader']
user_agent = UserAgent()
for url in urls:
        data = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
        title = soup.find_all("title")
        bar_list = []
        for b in title:
            result = b.text.strip()
            bar_list.append(result)
        print(bar_list)    
        ex = pd.DataFrame({"title": bar_list,})
        print(ex)
        ex.to_excel('sasa.xlsx', index=False)
```

I want to get both urls but my code gives me only one [shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhRr6.jpg)

Any other methods are appreciated I m new to these libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for url in urls` is indeed iterating over both urls, however the `ex.to_excel('sasa.xlsx', index=False)` line will overwrite `'sasa.xlsx'` on the second loop.

I would recommend either:

- Changing the filename on the second loop, or
- Writing the results to different sheets of the same excel file, like [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46437/how-to-write-multiple-data-frames-in-an-excel-sheet)